# About printing out a polynomial

Tags: java

This is part of a class that store and evaluate a polynomial of input number
And here is the method

```
public class Polynomial{
int coef,power;

public Polynomial(int maxPower){
}

public void setTerm(int coefficient, int power) {
    this.coef = coefficient;
    this.power = power;
}
```

And the input parameters in main method

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Polynomial q = new Polynomial(2);
    q.setTerm(2, 0);
    q.setTerm(0, 1);
    q.setTerm(3, 2);
    System.out.println(q);
}
```

And There is a toString method to print out the polynomial looks like this

```
public String toString(){
    return 
}
```

I kept encountering the problem where the setTerm method only read the last input parameters which is q.setTerm(3,2), and I think the first two were replaced. What can I do?

Comment: This wont work. Everytime you call setTerm, you override the older one. I suggest you use a List/Map of coeff-power pairs to approach this problem. Essentially define a class Term which contains coeff and power as members and a List of Terms as a member to Polynomial class.

Comment: @ArunavSanyal:  That's almost good enough to become an answer; you should consider making your comment one.

Comment: Yea, I simplified it a little and put the answer,

Comment: Thank you all so much for helping. I considered and tried about List before, and in fact I am still learning and not familiar with it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in your example we have to remember the previously seen terms.

I will do it via a map as the follows.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by arunavs on 9/28/16.
 */
public class Polynomial {

    // Key is power, value is coeff.
    private Map<Integer, Integer> powerToCoeffMap = new HashMap<>();

    // Maximal power allowed for polynomial.
    private int maxPower;


    public Polynomial(int maxPower){
        this.maxPower = maxPower;
    }

    public void setTerm(int coefficient, int power) {
        if (power > maxPower) {
           // throw some exception here. 
        }
        powerToCoeffMap.put(power, coefficient);
    }

    // terms may be rearranged in output. 
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        powerToCoeffMap.forEach((power, coeff) -> {builder.append(coeff + "x^" + power+ " ");});
        return builder.toString();
     }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Polynomial q = new Polynomial(2);
            q.setTerm(2, 0);
            q.setTerm(0, 1);
            q.setTerm(3, 2);
        System.out.println(q);
    }
}
```

Outputs : 2x^0 0x^1 3x^2

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice seeing a java 8 solution, you could use a TreeMap for ordered by power.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helps. I am learning and try to use Map now.

Answer (score 1):

You stored only one coef and one power.
The simplest is to have an array of coefficients indexed by power.

```
public class Polynomial {

    final int[] coefficients;

    public Polynomial(int maxPower) {
        coefficients = new int[maxPower + 1]; // All zero.
    }

    public void setTerm(int coefficient, int power) {
        coefficients[power] = coefficient;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = newStringBuilder();
        for (int power = 0; power < coefficients.length; ++power) {
            if (coefficients[power] != 0) {
                if (coefficients[power] > 0 && sb.length() > 0) {
                    sb.append('+');
                }
                sb.append(coefficients[power]);
                if (power > 0) {
                    sb.append('x');
                    if (power > 1) {
                        sb.append('^').append(power);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using array before too. There was a private int terms[] that I did't put up. I messed it with power and coefficient and could never get a correct array. Your idea is very clear and helpful, thanks!!

Comment: The constructor with maxPower seemed to aim at an array for powers from 0 upto maxPower. Other powers, negative and larger are not possible, and the array is _sparse_, x^100 would need an array of 101 entries. The map type of solution is more general (and a bit more indirect) but does not need a maxPower.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible implementation with the possibility of adding multiple terms at once could look like this:

```
package de;

import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Polynomial {
    //Private Fields
    private TreeMap<Integer, Integer> polys = new TreeMap<>();

    public Polynomial() {

    }
    public Polynomial(int... args){
        if(args.length < 2) polys.put(0, args[0]);

        for(int i= 0; i < args.length && i+1 < args.length; i = i+2){
            //                        coeff                      power
        polys.put(Integer.valueOf(args[i+1]), Integer.valueOf(args[i]));
        }
        if((args.length % 2) != 0){
            polys.put(0, args[args.length-1]);
        }
    }
    public void setTerm(int coeff, int power){
        polys.put(Integer.valueOf(power),Integer.valueOf(coeff));
    }

    public void setTerms(int... args){
        if(args.length < 2) polys.put(0, args[0]);

        for(int i= 0; i < args.length && i+1 < args.length; i = i+2){
            //                        coeff                      power
        polys.put(Integer.valueOf(args[i+1]), Integer.valueOf(args[i]));
        }
        if((args.length % 2) != 0){
            polys.put(0, args[args.length-1]);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Integer key : polys.descendingKeySet()){
            Integer value = polys.get(key);
            if(value == 0) continue;
            if(value > 0 && sb.length() != 0) sb.append("+");

            sb.append(value.toString());
            if(key == 1) sb.append("x");
            if(key > 1) sb.append("x^" + key);

            }
            return sb.toString();
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polynomial p = new Polynomial(1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, 7, 0);
        p.setTerm(17, 5);
        p.setTerms(23, 4, 0, 6);
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
}
```

Output: 17x^5+23x^4-3x^3-2x^2+1x+7

It orders from highest power to lowest power, prints x instead of x^1 and doesn't print x^0.

Comment: I get your idea. Although there's one polynomial to print out in me question, but there's more ad I didn't put up because I originally was trying  to get some ideas of what I can do instead of just look at the whole solutions from your all. Though I think I can modified based on yours. Still thank you a lot.

Comment: @user6896477 If you found a solution you like, consider accepting that answer so other people looking at this post know you found a solution and that there is a solution.